# CoreMediaIO, an alleged OS Bug / Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, core-audio, core-video

### Environment

- OS-X 10.10
- xcode 6.4
- C++/Obj-C OS-X application

### Use-case

- Capture video using CoreMediaIO, capture source is iPod5
- Capturing machine is OS-X Yosemite
- Capture feed consists of Video and Audio samples

### Problem description

While video capture is working fine, when video samples are received, there is an accumulating memory leak, when no video samples are received ( only audio ), there is no leak ( memory consumption stops growing )

I am mixing Cocoa thread and POSIX threads, I have made sure to have [NSThread isMultiThreaded] set to YES ( by creating an empty NSThread )

"Obj-C Auto Ref Counting" is set to YES in the project properties

The following is a short code-snap of the code causing the leak:

```
OSStatus status = 0;
@autoreleasepool {
    m_udid = udid;
    if (0 != (status = Utils::CoreMediaIO::FindDeviceByUDID(m_udid, m_devId)))
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND);
    if (0 != (status = Utils::CoreMediaIO::GetStreamByIndex(m_devId, kCMIODevicePropertyScopeInput, 0, m_strmID)))
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_FOUND);
    status = Utils::CoreMediaIO::SetPtopertyData(m_devId, kCMIODevicePropertyExcludeNonDALAccess, 1U);
    status = Utils::CoreMediaIO::SetPtopertyData<int>(m_devId, kCMIODevicePropertyDeviceMaster, getpid());// Exclusive access for the calling process

    // Results in an infinitely accumulating memory leak
    status = CMIOStreamCopyBufferQueue(m_strmID, [](CMIOStreamID streamID, void* token, void* refCon) {
                                                    @autoreleasepool {
                                                        CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer;
                                                        while(0 != (sampleBuffer = (CMSampleBufferRef)CMSimpleQueueDequeue(m_queueRef))) {
                                                            CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
                                                            sampleBuffer = 0;
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }, this, &m_queueRef);
    if(noErr != status)
        return E_FAIL;
    if(noErr != (status = CMIODeviceStartStream(m_devId, m_strmID)))
        return E_FAIL;
}
```

Having sample de-queuing done in the main thread ( using 'dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{' ) didn't have any affect...

**Is there anything wrong with the above code snap? might this be an OS Bug?**
Reference link: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/46752#46752

### AN UPDATE

The QuickTime player support using an iOS device as a capture source ( mirroring it's A/V to the mac machine ), having a preview session running for a while reproduce the above mentioned problem w/ the OS provided QuickTime player, this strongly indicate an OS Bug, bellow is a screen-shot showing the QT player taking **140Mb** of RAM after running for ~**2**hours ( where it starts around **20Mb** ), by the end of the day it has grown to **~760Mb**...
[image]

**APPLE Please have this Fixed, I have standing customers commitments...**

Comment: If you think this is a bug you should report it at http://bugreporter.apple.com to ensure it gets the proper (in)attention

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem ? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Well, the problem still exist w/ the latest OS-X, as a quick solution I have switched to libimobiledevice screenshot svc + Audio capture via the headset Jack, this however, result in a low quality video capture, the real, long-term solution should be either to reverse-engineer the iOS USB Mirroring protocol and implement it directly, OR, implement air-play, see these links of details: https://github.com/watson/airplay-server, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5GlZp6L9P4